# Does it matter to filter results when doing aggregation?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get my sales for each day which is located in my orders_summary table.

orders_summary table columns: id, date, amount, sku_id

products table columns: id, sku

Currently Im getting my daily sales like this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN os.date = '01/01/2022' THEN COALESCE(amount,0)::INT ELSE 0 END) AS orders_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN os.date = '01/02/2022' THEN COALESCE(amount,0)::INT ELSE 0 END) AS orders_2
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN orders_summary AS os ON p.id = os.sku_id
WHERE p.id = '1'
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Is it important to add `AND date BETWEEN '01/01/2022' AND '01/02/2022'` in my where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes absolutely. Imagine having 10 years worth of data in the table where you're only interested in the data for two days. You must use the `where` clause which restricts the number of rows (down to 0.05% in this case) *before* doing the `group by`.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same but wasn't sure

Comment: Yes, if you google "order of execution of sql query" you'll find that the order is where > group by > aggregate functions > select. Eliminate unnecessary rows in where clause to reduce load on group by.

Comment: btw when I add `AND date BETWEEN '01/01/2022' AND '01/02/2022'`, if I don't have any sales in orders summary, I get no rows in result. Is it possible to get 0 for orders_1 and orders_2 even when I don't have any rows for sku in orders_summary table?

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to use some kind of trick e.g. this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=5c4d411d13d3f1c34679fbe9e80571b7